# Timeout on Lambda function by requesting another function gives a timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the lambda function A with a user validator that requests a second lambda function B with the Bearer token and expects to receive the user information.

When I define the timeout of function A as *less than 28 seconds*, I receive the following error:

*ERROR: Get https://dev.url.com/auth/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)*

My code is:

```
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 20,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", m.authURL, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+m.token)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil || resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return errors.Errorf("Failed to request auth service.\ntoken: %s\nERROR: %+v\n", m.token, err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    log.Println(string(body))
    return err
```

---

When I define the timeout of function A as *higher or equal to 28 seconds* everything works as expected, both functions work correctly, and the whole process takes around 7ms (!!!).

Is it possible that a timeout has such role in the execution? If so, why?

Comment: It shouldn't. Is any of your Lambda in a VPC by any chance? Also, try creating the request outside the Lambda handler function.

Comment: Requesting outside of the function works without a problem. I suspect also of VPC because I configured to have internet access from my lambda. How could I verify whether is the VPC causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom might come by with the same issue, as mentioned in the comments above, my lambda function was inside of a VPC. I questioned my VPC configurations at the beginning, but because sometimes the execution between both lambdas was successfully executed, I eliminated that hypothesis since early.

Still don't understand why increasing the timeout of my lambda could make it work. I run out of assumptions and Suraj's comment encouraged me to reset my VPC configurations and instead of doing the configurations based on my experience, tried to follow every detail in the following [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/). During the process, realised that previously I assigned the public route table to the private subnet. That seems to explain the problem.